# Stop autodiscover hitting primary domain url

Tags: .htaccess

On my site I'm seeing a huge number of access log entries for autodiscover.xml.

At the moment as a work around I have a 302 rule in place:

```
RewriteRule ^autodiscover/(.*)$ http://autodiscover.mysite.com/autodiscover/$1 [r=302,l,nc]
```

However I think due to other required rewrite rules, this may not be resolving correctly.

I have read that by default autodiscover will try to resolve and the primary domain url, before trying any other possible url endpoints.

Can exchange server be configured so autodiscover does not try and resolve it's endpoint on my site?

Answer (score 1):

The hit from the AutoDiscovery URL is an Outlook approach (see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124251(v=exchg.160).aspx) for more info´s). So you couldn´t configure Exchange to change that behavior. The exchange server only host the autodiscover.xml and the content from it, but do not control the AutoDiscovery process.

The way it works is the following (more info's [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124251(v=exchg.160).aspx)):

1. Outlook is starting
2. User enter his email address
3. Outlook is then trying to find the AutoDiscovery configuration and follow a rule here in order to find the file (which is hosted on MS Exchange) based on the email domain from the email address the user entered.

   However you can configure Outlook to exclude some options. For example for a Windows based Outlook version you can do the following (see [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/267-speed-up-the-exchange-outlook-autodiscovery-process.html) for more infos):

   - PreferLocalXML (more infos [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc837949(office.12).aspx))
   - ExcludeHttpRedirect
   - ExcludeHttpsAutodiscoverDomain
   - ExcludeHttpsRootDomain
   - ExcludeScpLookup
   - ExcludeSrvRecord

It would be also possible to give the Outlook client a pre-configured XML with the needed settings. You can also [disable the AutoDiscovery fully](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/275-disable-autodiscovery-for-microsoft-office-for-mac.html) if needed. However this is something your Exchange administrator must design as a unexpected change from above might cause issues for the users.

If everything fails you might come up with a own autodiscover.xml which you provide (more info's can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc511507.aspx)). Via that way you could provide the needed infos for the Outlook clients (but you should do that with the Exchange Administrator).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - very helpful. I'll pass it on to my admins